# How to retrieve memory type (rdimm or udimm)?

Tags: memory, hardware, dell, report

i've some DELL servers, some have registered dimm memory, others have unbuffered dimm. Do you know any way to programaticaly get this info ? wmi class win32_physicalmemory doesnt seem to help on this point.
I can see the info in dell open manage, but i've to lauch it on each of server...

Comment: The Serial Presence Detect article in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Presence_Detect#Reading_and_writing_SPD_information) may be of some use here...

Comment: @DeerHunter i guess you have hit something but cant find easy way to dump info from the spd on windows .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the Dell service tag ident and then plug this into the Dell website to lookup the system, that might tell you.

Comment: Will tell you what the server shipped with, not necessarily what's in there now, though.  Kind of a major problem in a large environment.

Comment: True, although I finding that generally among a lot of companies they order and don't change.  If they every upgrade memory, it is about at the end of the warranty period (3 years) and just get a new computer instead of doing the upgrade.

Comment: I think I will go with this solution, thank you very much. For reference here is the url : http://support.euro.dell.com/support/DPP/Index.aspx?c=fr&cs=RC1077983&l=fr&s=pad&ServiceTag=XXXXXXX

Answer (score -2):

Use the diagnostic program called "Speccy.Exe"

https://www.piriform.com/speccy

Download the free version "Speccy.exe". It will install

Then run the program. It detects huge details of your system including the memory type!